# JavaScript with index error

Tags: javascript

When I click the "change lights" button I have to click it twice for the picture to change. What could be going wrong? Any ideas?

Here is my HTML:

```
<p>Click the button to change to the next light.</p>

<img id="starting_light" src="green.jpg">

<button type="button" onclick="nextLightClick()">Change</button>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
var gyr = new Array("green.jpg","yellow.jpg","red.jpg");

var index = 0;
var gyrLen = gyr.length;

function nextLightClick() {
    if (index == gyrLen) 
        index = 0;

    var image = document.getElementById('starting_light');
    image.src = gyr[index];

    index++;
}
```

I suspect the main problem to be in the JavaScript because once I started messing around with the variables the issue was introduced.

Comment: Just move the index++ to the first line of the function.

Comment: @apsillers that was an error on my half on the actual code they are the same I edited it to fix it and Zac I tried that but doesnt seem to work

Comment: @Zac "_Whenever_" is not the same as "_at the first click_"

Comment: did you mean `When` when"ever" you said `Whenever`?

Comment: @Andreas Zac is clearly correct. Look at the code. It doesn't only change the image every other time it's clicked.

Comment: zac is correct.

Comment: @Andreas, The issue is simply that the first 'change' does not change because its changing the image to the same thing. This will only be a problem the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time this runs, the image is green.

It then sets the image to gyr[0], the green image, then index is incremented.

You can either increment the index before setting the image, or reorder the array to have green be last.

Answer (score 2):

The first time you click the button, `index` is equal to 0, so `nextLightClick()` is setting image.src to "green.jpg", which is the same (assuming "1green.jpg" is a typo) as the starting image.

The solution is to move `index++` to the first line of `nextLightClick()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your index is still 0 on the first time you enter the function and set the image.

Move the index++; to the start of the function, or initialize the index to value 1.

```
var index = 1;
```

If you want to initialize the index to 1, then you should rename the variable to something like nextIndex.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is the case. Your code is working correctly. Your first image is green and the first time you click you are replacing it with the first image, that's the reason you don't see any difference.

You might consider doing it as:

```js
var gyr = new Array("http://i.imgur.com/eucAMTA.jpg", "http://is2.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple122/v4/be/9a/f0/be9af074-90f2-5894-99a0-17460783db6c/source/1200x630bf.jpg", "https://i0.wp.com/fusion.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/RED.jpg?resize=1600%2C900&quality=80&strip=all");



var index = 0;
var gyrLen = gyr.length;

function nextLightClick() {
   index++;
  // alert("hello" + index);
  if (index == gyrLen)
    index = 0;

  var image = document.getElementById('starting_light');
  image.src = gyr[index];

 
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
p>Click the button to change to the next light.</p>

<img id="starting_light" src="http://i.imgur.com/eucAMTA.jpg">

<button type="button" onclick="nextLightClick()">Change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah I seem to have found the answer thanks to Zac and American the problem was that index should have been at the first line of 'nexlightclick'

Fixed script below:

```
<p>Click the button to change to the next light.</p>

<img id="starting_light" src="green.jpg">

<button type="button" onclick="nextLightClick()">Change lights</button>

<script>

var gyr = new Array("green.jpg","yellow.jpg","red.jpg");



var index = 0;
var gyrLen = gyr.length;

function nextLightClick() {
    index++;
    if (index == gyrLen) 
        index = 0;

    var image = document.getElementById('starting_light');
    image.src = gyr[index];
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a little problem with `index` update logic. You must evaluate its value and if it's less than `gry.length` add one else reinitialize to 0.

The inside script code:

```
var gyr = new Array("green.jpg","yellow.jpg","red.jpg");
var index = 0;

function nextLightClick() {
    index = index + 1 < gyr.length ? index + 1 : 0;
    document.getElementById('starting_light').alt = gyr[index];
}
```